# Correct preposition in "The holes will be made in/to/at a diameter of 5 cm"

Tags: prepositions

> The holes will be made in/to/at a diameter of 5 cm.

I couldn’t decide which preposition is correct in the sentence above. What I want to say is diameter of hole will be 5 cm. Is it correct to make sentence in this way. If it is correct which preposition should I use?

Comment: What's wrong with "the holes are 5cm in diameter"? If you are not saying how the holes are made in this sentence, why bother to mention making them? It doesn't add anything to the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The way you built the sentence, it sounds like you either are Nostradamus, or you have a crystal ball.

If the sentence is supposed to be a requirement, then it should be:

> The holes must have a diameter of 5 cm.

or even better:

> The holes must have a 5 cm diameter.

---

Otherwise, you might say:

> The holes will be made / *drilled* **with** a diameter of 5 cm.

Comment: I got it . Would it be ok if i say “ The holes MUST be made in/to/at a diameter of 5 cm.

Comment: Your choice uses too many words. Also, a hole in the ground is _made_ (or rather, _dug_). A hole in a piece of wood / metal / ... is _drilled_. Also, I would still use the preposition "with".

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i still couldn’t understand difference between “in” and “with” in this sentence.

Comment: "in" implies inside, but a diameter has nothing "in". On the other hand, a circle has a "diameter". And the verb "has" suggests the use of "with".

Comment: I see no problem with "The holes will be made to a diameter of 5cm." It's just talking in a future imperative tense.

Comment: That's true, it is common to use "to" in the context of meeting a specification - "made to order", "working to a deadline", "repaired to the required standard".